# Issues Splitting values separated by delimiters and creating columns for each split in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am new to snowflake and I am trying to run an sql query that splits values with delimiters(`semi-column`) and create columns for each of them.

Table name: lexa

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-02-13 18:17:43;83.89.250.196;10.10.11.29 |
| 002 | 2021-02-13 17:47:56;5.33.18.24;10.10.11.28 |

what I am trying to achieve

| ID | register | Ip1 | IP2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 2021-02-13 18:17:43 | 83.89.250.196 | 10.10.11.29 |
| 002 | 2021-02-13 17:47:56 | 5.33.18.24 | 10.10.11.28 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snowflake [split](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split.html) function can split a string into an array.

```
SELECT ID,
       split(value, ';')[0] as register,
       split(value, ';')[1] as IP1,
       split(value, ';')[2] as IP2
  FROM data;
```

Comment: thanks for the contribution, the code works but each value had double quotes after the split

Comment: can the register be convered to timestamp pls

Comment: I saw someone else also had trouble with quotes after splitting ([here](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009FzVBSSA3/want-to-convert-comma-separated-values-to-single-table-when-i-use-split-and-flatten-function-getting-result-in-double-quotes-can-i-get-values-without-)). But I guess you could just replace them. Also try [split_part](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/split_part.html): `split_part(value, ';', 1) as register`.

Comment: Conversion to timestamp should be doable with TO_TIMESTAMP function. Please check Snowflake's [SQL function reference](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference-functions.html), their documentation is pretty good.